# circular array Queue (conceptual)

Tags: java, queue

for circular arrays Queues, is a scenario possible where back < front and size < capacity?

or is that when back< front, size always equals capacity?

Thank You

Comment: I think that the answer is "yes".  But you really, really need to define your terms before someone can give you a proper (i.e. understandable) answer.  Or at least, point to some site where you are getting the info from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, back < front and size < capacity is valid state in a circular buffer/queue. Note that size is generally implicit and calculated as `(back-front)%capacity`. The Wikipedia article on circular buffers has a great description of how circular buffers function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer